# How to convert one CSV column contaning JSON values into 4 different columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV called Parsing.csv and the contents are displayed as below

```
userid            data_to_parse
54f3ad9a29ada   "value":"N;U;A7;W"}]
54f69f2de6aec   "value":"N;U;I6;W"}]
54f650f004474   "value":"Y;U;A7;W"}]
54f52e8872227   "value":"N;U;I1;W"}]
54f64d3075b72   "value":"Y;U;A7;W"}]
54f69dc01793f   "value":"N;U;A1;W"}]
54f5d26833ce6   "value":"N;U;A1;W"}]
54f52b1a7e647   "value":"N;U;A4;W"}]
54f4ae7da8d01   "value":"N;U;A1;W"}]
54f6290ca187d   "value":"N;U;U;W"}]
```

I have read this dataframe using

```
Parsing = pd.read_csv("data/Parsing.csv")
```

Now I wanted Parse out the values (stored in the “data_to_parse” column) into four separate columns.

So for example, the four additional columns for the first entry would have values of “N”, “you”, “A7”, and “W”. This data basically comes from JSON blobs.
How can I achieve it ?

Tried this but it gives me an error, saying it doesn't recoqnize JSON in pandas attribute error

```
 v=pd.io.json.json_normalize
(Parsing.data_to_parse.apply(pd.json.loads).tolist())
```

expected output:1st entry in the dataframe with different columns will be as below--

```
userid        | value1| value2| value3| value4
54f3ad9a29ada | N     |  U    |    A7 | W
```

Comment: Please provide an actual sample data not an image, along with a complete  expected output

Comment: @Chris updated  the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, one way is to make them a proper `json` and use `pandas.Series.str.split`:

```
s = ("{" + df["data_to_parse"].str.strip("]")).apply(pd.io.json.loads)
df2 = s.str["value"].str.split(";", expand=True)
new_df = pd.concat([df, df2.add_prefix("value")], axis=1)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
          userid         data_to_parse value0 value1 value2 value3
0  54f3ad9a29ada  "value":"N;U;A7;W"}]      N      U     A7      W
1  54f69f2de6aec  "value":"N;U;I6;W"}]      N      U     I6      W
2  54f650f004474  "value":"Y;U;A7;W"}]      Y      U     A7      W
3  54f52e8872227  "value":"N;U;I1;W"}]      N      U     I1      W
4  54f64d3075b72  "value":"Y;U;A7;W"}]      Y      U     A7      W
5  54f69dc01793f  "value":"N;U;A1;W"}]      N      U     A1      W
6  54f5d26833ce6  "value":"N;U;A1;W"}]      N      U     A1      W
7  54f52b1a7e647  "value":"N;U;A4;W"}]      N      U     A4      W
8  54f4ae7da8d01  "value":"N;U;A1;W"}]      N      U     A1      W
9  54f6290ca187d   "value":"N;U;U;W"}]      N      U      U      W
```

Comment: Genius! Thanks so much @chris